# How to create a cube from two planes?

Tags: mesh

I am looking for a method to automatically join the vertices of two meshes that are stacked one upon the another. To be specific, how to create a cube from two planes, that are stacked one upon another with small distance in one of the axis.

Comment: Are those 2 planes in the same object?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Consider taking the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and checking out sections of the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help). Besides the information @Denis sought, what do you mean by "automatically".

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information given, I think that the loop tools addon should help you. If you don't have it enabled then go to your user preferences and enable it.

This will require both planes to be a single object, so start by joining them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Now, in the *tool shelf*, go to the loop tools section and with both opposing faces selected (which will be the inside of the 'cube') click the bridge tool (highlighted in yellow). If you have missing faces after the bridge operation then tick the *remove faces* option (highlighted in red) so it is disabled and the faces will come back.

[image]